# Why would MariaDB return nothing through Python to a query that works fine every other way?

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi, mariadb

I have a functioning MariaDB server. It works as expected when logged into locally with its own client software, or when connected to from a remote machine via, for example, Navicat. When connected in these ways, it responds to all `SELECT` and `INSERT` commands as expected.

However I can not get it to respond to Python and it does not even return an error.

Here is test code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import mysql.connector as mariadb
# import mariadb

class dbQuery:

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=8457, user='root', password='XXXXX', database='empowerment')
            self.cursor = self.mariadb_connection.cursor()
        except:
            print("Error")

    def query(self):
        query = "SELECT 1+1;"
        try:
            ans = self.cursor.execute(query)
        except:
            print("Error")
        print("ans1: ",ans)
        return ans

    def __del__(self):
        self.mariadb_connection.close()

thisQuery = dbQuery()
ans = thisQuery.query()
print("ans2: ",ans)
```

ans1 and ans2 both print `None` with both mysql.connector and with the (beta) mariadb connector. None of the exceptions are ever thrown. If I `print` the connection or cursor variables, they seem to have valid contents at the appropriate points in the code. Only the output of `execute` seems wrong. This is on Raspberry Pi OS, if that matters.

What might I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql.connector` is based on the *Python Database API Specification v2.0* ([link](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id14))
And `execute` method returns `None`
To get the result of the query, you need to use method like `fetchall` or
you need to iterate through the `cursor` object itself.
So your `query` method should be something like the following:

```py
    def query(self):
        query = "SELECT 1+1;"
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(query)
            ans = self.cursor.fetchall()
        except:
            print("Error")
        print("ans1: ",ans)
        return ans
```